# extjs 4 grid horizontal scrolling if need

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

How can I make a horizontal-scrolling data table, only when it is needed?

I sketched out a simple illustrative [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q84).

Comment: try  scrollable: {
                      direction: 'horizontal'
                 }

Comment: I don't think there is simple solution in your case. Because the grid already have the date rows in there, so the scrollbar will be always displayed, you have it only hidden by grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            cls: 'body',
            width: 200,
            height: 300,
            layout:{
                 tableAttrs: {
                      style: {width:'100%'}
                 },
                 type:'table'
             },
            autoScroll: true,
```

Thx, I decided my problem this stub code.